# (MSSQL) SUM COLUMN BY MODIFIED DATE GIVEN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the sum on a specific date given e.g from 18/12/04 to 18/12/15 then calculate the total amount

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is in the GROUP BY statement.

If you want to get the sum per tenant and date, group by them both.

If you want to get the sum per date, group by date only (and remove the tenant colums [or select MAX] from the SELECT).

Paste your code as text and I can edit it for you if you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the total as additional column, you can use `WINDOW` functions:

```
SELECT tenant_id
      ,SUM(total_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY tenant_id)
      ,SUM(total_amount) OVER ()
FROM tenant_reeipits
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```